# Access Parent page name in Radwindow

Tags: javascript, c#-4.0, telerik

Is there any way we get to know from which page the radwindow got called/opened from?
I have one RadWindow which will be opened by two pages,So if I can know the name of the page I can check on that and execute different Code.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

absolutely: this is currenlty what I have in my project and its working in production:

here is the Code inside the Child Window

```
  function GetRadWindow() {
            var oWindow = null;
            if (window.radWindow)
                oWindow = window.radWindow;
            else if (window.frameElement.radWindow)
                oWindow = window.frameElement.radWindow;
            return oWindow;
        }

function GetparentWindowname()
{
var _ParentName=GetRadWindow().BrowserWindow.document.location.href;
alert(_ParentName);
}
```

Regards